Checking if user has enrolled facial recognition
I have an application that checks if the user has facial recognition and fingerprint recognition for biometric purposes.
I have to do two checks for each type of biometric.
Check 1 - Check if the device supports the specified biometric.
Check 2 - Check if the user has used the biometric with biometric registration.
I have two methods to do this for me:
private fun isFaceEnrolled(): Boolean {
        val packageManager = packageManager
        val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)

        val hasFaceHardware = packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FACE)

        val canAuthenticateWithFace = biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG) == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS

        return hasFaceHardware && canAuthenticateWithFace
    }

    private fun isFingerprintEnrolled(): Boolean {
        val packageManager = packageManager
        val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)

        val hasFingerprintHardware = packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)

        val canAuthenticateWithFingerprint = biometricManager.canAuthenticate(
            BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG
        ) == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS

        return hasFingerprintHardware && canAuthenticateWithFingerprint
    }

I had a problem with a test where the device supports facial biometrics but the user's face is not scanned, i.e., he/she did not use this biometric.
Even so, the "isFaceEnrolled" method is returning true.
Is there something in it that I didn't check correctly?

"I have an application that checks if the user has facial recognition and fingerprint recognition for biometric purposes." -- that information is not made available to apps. All your code is doing is seeing if a particular form of biometrics is possible and that the user used some form of strong biometrics. So, on a device that supports both face recognition and fingerprint scanning, both methods will return true if the user has enabled any form of strong biometrics.

Hey man, thanks for explaining. So, is there no way to differentiate on Android the type of biometrics supported and whether the user scanned it? I read about "strong" and "weak", but in my case I need to distinguish between "face" and "fingerprint"

"So, is there no way to differentiate on Android the type of biometrics supported and whether the user scanned it?" -- if by "type of biometrics" you mean face, fingerprint, etc., then correct, apps cannot distinguish those.

Your code is only checking face recognition/fingerprint capabilities of the device. That's why it's returning true because the device has face recognition/fingerprint support. Once the user register face recognition/fingerprint, you need to manually save the value, preferably to a sharedpreference file (if you want the value to persist even after the app is finished) and then access that value from sharedpreference file when you want to check whether Face recognition/fingerprint is registered or not. Your current code can't help you with that as it's only a basic way to check device capabilities regarding FR/FP. It's not designed to save app specific registration values

hey bro, thans for the answer. My question is: Is it possible to check if user has registered face recognition and fingerprint separately in Kotlin? that's is what I need.

@DiChrist As far as I know, no. And most probably Android will never allow it due to privacy & security issues, unless app specific biometrics is introduced. If apps are able to determine what type of biometrics is used system-wide, that's not good

"I had a problem with a test where the device supports facial biometrics but the user's face is not scanned, i.e., he/she did not use this biometric." BTW what you mean by this? Why should the user's face be scanned if he/she never enrolled face recognition? Whether face recognition will be used or not is dependent on its registration. If it wasn't registered, it wont be used
